# How to redirect every uri calls to one controller, except some static ones?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I'm using codeigniter and want to make my portal a bit more SEO friendly.
I have a controller (articles) which handles every article on my portal. 
The URL looks like this:

`example.com/articles/category-sub-category/article-name`

I'm using mod rewrite module to hide my index.php, and codeigniter routing to hide the controller action that handles every call.

I want to hide articles too, but if I hide it, every call goes to the articles controller, and that's not what I want, because I want my URL to look like this:

`example.com/category-sub-category/article-name`

I've tried it with regexp routing rules in the routes.php but I found no way to make it right.

Comment: May be it's just me, but I have no idea what these "articles" are and why do you want to hide it. And why do you want to hide anything

Comment: I want to hide it because i want a very good seo url for my site.
"articles" is the name of my controller. I call it through uri, if I call it like in my first example its not the best option I think, because is use the portal in more different languages, im using different categories, and i think ill get a better ranking in every language if the article action call isn't there. (sorry for my bad command of language)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered this one pretty extensively a few days ago:

[How to get an array of all controllers in a Codeigniter project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797495/how-to-get-an-array-of-all-controllers-in-a-codeigniter-project/2801866#2801866)

Answer (score 3):

Using CI's routing feature, you'd have to set a route for every category like so..

```
$route['category_one/:any'] = 'articles/category/category_one';
$route['category_two/:any'] = 'articles/category/category_two';
//.. and on and on until you've routed them all
```

You'd have to have a `category` method in your `Articles` controller or else you'd also have to create a method for each category, which would get way out of hand.

At least with CodeIgniter, you'd be better off keeping the `articles` part in your url and doing it like this:

```
$route['articles/(:any)'] = 'articles/category/$1';
```

You'd still need to create the `category` method in your controller, though.

Comment: Ok, thats how i do it right now, but i need a non-static way for doing this. I'm pretty sure that theres an other way with regex or so (only problem, that i do not know how to). Ive tried it with following syntax: 
$route['#[^articles]/:any#'] = "$1/$2";
but it wont work

Comment: Why are you using $route['#[^articles]/:any#'] = "$1/$2"; You don't need the regex start/stop, so that would be $route['articles/(:any)'] = "$1/$2"; The () mean you can use $1, but you are only matching one thing so $2 doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

ok! problem solved!

I've found the solution for my problem, on following site:
http://bizwidgets.biz/web-design/codeigniter-routes-trick-removing-controller-names-from-the-uri-to-keep-urls-short/

`$route['^(?!account|about|showcase|etc).*'] = "articles/read/$0";`

This line returns every non-controller requests to my articles controller, so i have urls as i wanted to have :)

Comment: Congrats! But just so you know, not to being a jerk here, but every request is technically a controller request. You're just re-routing everything that is not requesting the account, about, showcase, etc controller to the articles controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^articles(?:/|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^static1(?:/|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^static2(?:/|$)
...
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /articles/$1 [QSA,NE]
```

Comment: This is a good way, but not a codeigniter way to solve the problem. It's pretty much the same thing, so thanks!