# CodeIgniter get all controller list with its method

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to create user role and permission based on controller method. For this i needed a list of controllers with its method.

i want it to dynamically if i add a method into any class than it will list in this listing

For that i tried this into my method But the problem is that its only showing the current controller and its method.:

```
<?php
$controller = $this->router->fetch_class();
$method = $this->router->fetch_method();
?>
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Review this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177864/get-all-functions-name-from-all-controllers-in-codeigniter

Comment: Thanks @yogesh thats exactly i wants.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an array of all controllers in a Codeigniter project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797495/how-to-get-an-array-of-all-controllers-in-a-codeigniter-project)

Answer (score 3):

Use this library to get all Codeigniter class with yours methods. On **application/config/autoload.php**, you need load **Controllerlist**.

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/***
 * File: (Codeigniterapp)/libraries/Controllerlist.php
 * 
 * A simple library to list all your controllers with their methods.
 * This library will return an array with controllers and methods
 * 
 * The library will scan the "controller" directory and (in case of) one (1) subdirectory level deep
 * for controllers
 * 
 * Usage in one of your controllers:
 * 
 * $this->load->library('controllerlist');
 * print_r($this->controllerlist->getControllers());
 * 
 * @author Peter Prins 
 */

class ControllerList {

    /**
     * Codeigniter reference 
     */
    private $CI;
    private $EXT;

    /**
     * Array that will hold the controller names and methods
     */
    private $aControllers;

    // Construct
    function __construct() {
        // Get Codeigniter instance 
        $this->CI = get_instance();
        $this->CI->EXT = ".php";

        // Get all controllers 
        $this->setControllers();
    }

    /**
     * Return all controllers and their methods
     * @return array
     */
    public function getControllers() {
        return $this->aControllers;
    }

    /**
     * Set the array holding the controller name and methods
     */
    public function setControllerMethods($p_sControllerName, $p_aControllerMethods) {
        $this->aControllers[$p_sControllerName] = $p_aControllerMethods;
    }

    /**
     * Search and set controller and methods.
     */
    private function setControllers() {
        // Loop through the controller directory
        foreach(glob(APPPATH . 'controllers/*') as $controller) {

            // if the value in the loop is a directory loop through that directory
            if(is_dir($controller)) {
                // Get name of directory
                $dirname = basename($controller, $this->CI->EXT);

                // Loop through the subdirectory
                foreach(glob(APPPATH . 'controllers/'.$dirname.'/*') as $subdircontroller) {
                    // Get the name of the subdir
                    $subdircontrollername = basename($subdircontroller, $this->CI->EXT);

                    // Load the controller file in memory if it's not load already
                    if(!class_exists($subdircontrollername)) {
                        $this->CI->load->file($subdircontroller);
                    }
                    // Add the controllername to the array with its methods
                    $aMethods = get_class_methods($subdircontrollername);
                    $aUserMethods = array();
                    foreach($aMethods as $method) {
                        if($method != '__construct' && $method != 'get_instance' && $method != $subdircontrollername) {
                            $aUserMethods[] = $method;
                        }
                    }
                    $this->setControllerMethods($subdircontrollername, $aUserMethods);                                      
                }
            }
            else if(pathinfo($controller, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == "php"){
                // value is no directory get controller name                
                $controllername = basename($controller, $this->CI->EXT);

                // Load the class in memory (if it's not loaded already)
                if(!class_exists($controllername)) {
                    $this->CI->load->file($controller);
                }

                // Add controller and methods to the array
                $aMethods = get_class_methods($controllername);
                $aUserMethods = array();
                if(is_array($aMethods)){
                    foreach($aMethods as $method) {
                        if($method != '__construct' && $method != 'get_instance' && $method != $controllername) {
                            $aUserMethods[] = $method;
                        }
                    }
                }

                $this->setControllerMethods($controllername, $aUserMethods);                                
            }
        }   
    }
}
// EOF
```

Comment: Thank you for this code. It works amazingly for my project. For my purposes, I can list the controllers as user applications, and the functions as assignable tools. I like that you do not include the private functions. In order to hide functions, I prepend them with a character set like 'a_' and use a regex to skip them. `/^(index)|^\_|^([a-z]\_)/`